# Angular15 - canActivate based on values stored in BehaviorSubject in oher service

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router, behaviorsubject, angular-guards

I have `PermissionsService` which stores user's permissions. These are loaded from API by `HttpClient` after user's successful auth process (after login I call the `getUserGroupsWithModelPermissions()` which loads user's permission groups, and then I sum these permissions into `_resolvedUserPermissions` BehaviorSubject)

In every component I need these user's permissions, I subscribe to `resolvedUserPermissions$`, and after receiving data, I use other methods (ex. `resolveModelPermission()` where I pass data from `subscribe`) from `ModelPermissionsService` to do business logic and it works well.

Example usage in components:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.$permissions = this.permissionsService.resolvedUserPermissions$.subscribe(data => {
      this.canSeeProducts = this.permissionsService.resolveModelPermission(data, 'Products', PermissionScope.Read);
    })
  }
```

Permissions Service:

```
export class ModelPermissionService {

  private _resolvedUserPermissions = new BehaviorSubject<ModelFieldPermissions[]>([]); 
  public resolvedUserPermissions$ = this._resolvedUserPermissions.asObservable();

  public getUserGroupsWithModelPermissions(): void {
    this.httpClient.get<ApiResponse<UserGroups[]>>(userEndpoint + '/me/permissions', httpOptions)
    .subscribe({
      next: data => {
        this._resolvedUserPermissions.next(this.sumUserPermissions(data.data));
      },
      error: err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    })
  }

public resolveModelPermission(userPermissions: ModelFieldPermissions[], modelName: string, permissionScope: PermissionScope):boolean {
    if(userPermissions.length > 0){
      // DO LOGIC HERE
    }
    return false;
  }


}
```

Now I need to use data from `resolvedUserPermissions$` in canActivate method in router guard service but I don't know how to subscribe to this `resolvedUserPermissions$`?

I need something like this:

```
canActivate(){
    this.modelPermissionService.resolvedUserPermissions$.subscribe(data =>{
        return this.modelPermissionService.resolveModelPermission(data, 'modelName', scope)
    })
}
```

All methods I found used pipe+map instead of subscribe but I had no permissions data. Example:

```
canActivate(){
    return this.getAccess()
}

getAccess(){
    this.permissionsService.resolvedUserPermissions$.pipe(
        map(data =>{
            //here data is empty, no logic to do, because no subscription?
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: You don't need to subscribe in `canActivate`. Just return Observable that emits boolean and completes. As side note, subscribing in service is bad idea. Mostly you don't need to subscribe at all, create operator chain with pipe() that creates desired result.

Comment: why ` getUserGroupsWithModelPermissions` is creatinga subscripiton? Your code is perfect example of how not to use Rx in your app.

Comment: @Antoniossss I saw such a solution in many courses and tutorials. I have more than 20 components using this data, what you would suggest to do instead of this?

Comment: Stop using those courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission Service:

```
export class ModelPermissionService {

 getUserGroupsWithModelPermissions(): Observable<ModelFieldPermissions[]> {
    this.httpClient.get<ApiResponse<UserGroups[]>>('yourpath', httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map(data => this.sumUserPermissions(data.data)),
        shareReplay(1), // probably you want to hold and re-use result from api
        tap(data=> concole.log(data)), // DEBUGGING
      );
  }

  resolveModelPermission(data, 'modelName', scope): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getUserGroupsWithModelPermissions().pipe(
      map(data=> / your code to extract permission from user data /),
    )
  }
}
```

in Resolver Service:

```
canActivate() {
    return this.modelPermissionService.resolveModelPermission(data, 'modelName', scope)
      .pipe(
        take(1), // Observable must complete!
        tap(data=> concole.log(data)), // DEBUGGING
      ),
}
```

Comment: Ok, it has worked, but now how to use this in my other many (more than 20) components? I tried something like this `ngOnInit() {
   this.permissionsService.resolveModelPermission2(someData, 'Orders', PermissionScope.Read).pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(data =>{ this.canSeeOrdersDetails = data})
    )
  }`
But I can't see any effects

Comment: Do I have to subscribe at the end?

Comment: No that's not necessary

Comment: Router internally subscribes to Observable returned from `canActivate`. In component you must subscribe to get results (and, of course, unsubscribe). Or, even better, use `async` pipe to do the job.

Comment: Ok I get this, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
canActivate(){
    return this.modelPermissionService.resolvedUserPermissions$.pipe(
         switchMap(data => this.modelPermissionService.resolveModelPermission(data, 'modelName', scope))
    )
}
```

Comment: Throws an error `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.ts(2322)`, so I tried `switchMap(async (data) => this.modelPermissionService.resolvePropertyPermission(data, 'modelName', scope))` but it doesn't work. I have no data in `data`.